# How to export emails from android stock email?

Tags: email

I need to get around 7000 emails off an Sony Xperia with Lollipop (5.1.1) that which has stock android email 8.0. Not worried about the format, just need to import them to a desktop client such as Thunderbird or Outlook.

The emails were from pop3 account.